# NPN TRANSISTOR POLARITY

Tags: transistors, npn, polarity

i am a mechanical engineer i have a question on a transistor. what happens if i apply a +ve terminal to base and negative terminal to emitter in a NPN transistor with no wires connected to the collector

Comment: Some current will flow from base to emitter.

Comment: The base/emitter junction will act like a diode, and conduct current.

Comment: If you do not limit the current, you will let all the magic smoke out. Just like ballbearings go up in smoke.

Comment: @PeterBennett move your comment to a answer.

Comment: if you invite a guy to answer, and nobody posts something better, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The base/emitter junction will act like a diode, and conduct current.